# How to get rid of the need of slide to unlock the screen?

Tags: android

I'm installing Android in a mobile without touch screen. I wonder if is there a way of turn of the screen lock, or unlock it some other way then slide the screen?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's referred to as the "keyguard" and can be [controlled with the KeyguardManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html)

Comment: Additionally, an example can be found at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html#UnlockDevice